# TextView can't change line In AutoCompleteTextView DropDownListVIew

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, dropdownlistview, listpopupwindow

I tested on Android Api 28.

I added a AutoCompleteTextView and it showed like below:

[image: error]

I have try:

1.setting lines =3,maxLines = 3,scrollHorizontally = true,inputType="textMultiLine",singleLine =true,and it made no change.

2.setting LayoutParams,and it showed like below:

[image: setting layoutparams].

similar case:[textview of autocompletetextview showing data in single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508643/textview-of-autocompletetextview-showing-data-in-single-line)

Answer (score 0):

Just need a LinerLayout to wrap the TextView in the layout of item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tv_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    tools:text="test--------------------------------------test" />
 </LinearLayout>
```